# I cannot get images to work on my django project(this is my first one and im having trouble)

Tags: python, css, django

I have an img folder in the same directory as my html files. I want to put images onto my site but I am doing something wrong.

this is the code:

```
{% block a %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 center">
        <img src="img/img01.jpeg">
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

this is what happens when I run the local server.

[image: local server]

this is my file directory

[image: file directory]

Answer (score 0):

Websites generally need to serve additional files such as images, JavaScript, or CSS. In Django, we refer to these files as “static files”.

Those files need to be handled another way as your templates. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/).

It comes basically down to defining a seperate static directory inside your app. It is really good explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't even want to tell you how long I spent trying to figure this out.